# cell font style in excel

Tags: excel, cell

Through this:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Italic = true;
```

All fonts become italic. For only a given cell to be italic what can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the **font property** rather than the *cell style property*
`Range("a1").Font.Italic = True` or `Cells(1, 2).Font.Italic = True`